# Change file type in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I created a text file, and renamed it into testTreeGen.py.

[image]

The problem is that PyCharm does not detect it as a python source so that I can't execute it.

How can I teach PyCharm that this is python script?
I tried remove the file and recreated it, and created another python file and renamed it; all ends up being the file as text file not Python script.

The version is 3.0.2.

[image]

### EDIT

Refactoring does **not** working.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The file property comes back to text (the original file property that I created before the first *refactoring*) even after I renamed it as python script.

The weird thing is that no matter where I create the `testTreeGen.py`, PyCharm creates it as a text file as if it remembers the name of the file should be text file. I can create python script anything but the `testTreeGen.py`.

Comment: Did you rename it using the refactor Shift+F6?

Comment: aren't there both options "add new file" and "add python file" in PyCharm? which version is it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I've been using pycharm for quite some time now, and I've never had this problem.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem, if not we can have a session.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | File Types | Text**

Check patterns there (bottom list) -- you must have had `testTreeGen` or similar pattern. Just remove it.

**UPDATE 2021-02-28:**

**Since 2020.3** version you should also check under `Auto-detect file type by content` file type.

See a bit more / with screenshots in this answer: [WebStorm File association system does not recognize a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700794/webstorm-file-association-system-does-not-recognize-a-file)

---

This usually happens when creating new file and instead of using specific file template you use `New | File` and forgetting to enter file extension (which is required here as opposed to specific file template which adds file extension automatically) -- this is to allow to create ANY file with any extension (e.g. `.htaccess` or just `README`).

Since such file (`testTreeGen` in your case) does not have extension, IDE does not know how to treat it and treats it as plain text (not automatically though -- it asking you to choose correct file type with "text file" type preselected, but vast majority of users just hitting enter instead of reading what that screen says -- *"relax, I'm a professional and I know what I'm doing"*).

Now, since the `testTreeGen` pattern is there and it is bigger/more precise that generic `*.rb` or `*.py`, file is treated as Text file regardless of file extension -- renaming will not help.

---

**Conclusion / advice** -- pay a bit more attention to confirmation dialogs.

Comment: For me, my file was under "auto detect file by ..."  in the list. Took me a while to get it.

Comment: @Guillaume Yes, it's a new entry since 2020.3 where it is often preselected by default instead of the "Text" entry. See this answer with screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700794/webstorm-file-association-system-does-not-recognize-a-file

Answer (score 11):

Go in the Settings -->Editor --> File Types --> Text --> Registered Patterns (lower list box in the dialog) --> Remove the file name that has been added (Should be the file name you accidentally created as text file) by clicking the "-" right hand side. Apply and you should have this speeding ticket off your record.

[image]

1. Select File Types
2. Scroll down until you see [text]
3. select [text]
4. scroll down to the bottom, you should see your file that Pycharm thinks is text
5. hit the [-] option to remove the text association and hit OK
6. When you go back to Project view you should see the file associated with the extension you gave it.

Comment: My file was not listed in "Text" but in "Auto-detect file type by content". That menu can also be found in the list of "Recognized File Types" (even if I would not regard it as a "file type" on its own, which I find confusing.)

Answer (score 3):

I cannot say for sure what mistake you've made, however, this is the way to properly rename a file:

[image]
[image]
[image]

If the above fails for whatever reason, try the following, otherwise this is bug that you need to report:

[image]

Comment: @Games Brainiac : Refactoring does not solve this issue on my Mac and PyCharm. I updated my post.

Comment: @prosseek Aha! I found out what the problem is. This is intelliJ's error, I can't even _see_ the file here. The best way to solve this is just just copy all your stuff, as in your `src` folder and your `test` folder, and then just paste it into a new directory, and then _repoen_ pycharm in that directory. Your `.idea` folder will be regenerated, and thus this problem will be solved.

Comment: Actually better idea, just delete your `.idea` directory, and restart pycharm in that directory.

Comment: @Games Brainiac: I didn't do exactly what you proposed; I also removed .idea folder, but it didn't work. I guess it's cache problem. I added my own answer.

Comment: @prosseek Sorry, I couldn't help. I mean its hard to debug these kinds of problems when you're not next to the person.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem and you probably have to look in Settings -->Editor --> File Types --> Auto-detect file type by content

[This is where it can go wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjg9P.png)

[This is where to possibly fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcEfX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the the `.idea` folder, I cleared the cache using the `File-> Invalidate Chache` menu option, I deleted the `__pycache__` folders. I also tried to check out a new version into a new folder as well as copy and pasted the relevant files into a new folder.

None of the solutions worked so it seems that if you declare the file wrongly it is globally registered in all projects as this wrong file type.

I just reinstalled PyCharm deleting all settings. However, if I would have had more custom plugs-ins or settings, I would have started playing with the global pycharm settings rather than the project settings. One option might be deleting the `C:\User\<username>\.PyCharm<version>` folder which should contain the config, this resetting your PyCharm to factory settings. Obviously do not want to replicate the error now.

My short version: The file type is not saved in the project folder so if you do not find a menu option to change it, go and play with the global settings which are saved in the in the folder mentioned above.