# Why Pycharm won't recognize my python file?

Tags: pycharm

I have placed several python files in folder that has a name `last_name first_name project assembler`. For some reason, `Assembler.py` is not being recognized:

[image: Assembler.py is not recognized, but the other three are]

Why is this? Does it have to do with the fact that the folder contains the name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | File Types | Text**

I had the same issue. Check patterns -- you must added a similar pattern to the Text File Type. Just remove it.

Full answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281563/7551702