# Can't create file with name "Searchable" in Laravel, why?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I want to create trait in Laravel with name `Searchable`, but PhpStorm do not identified the file as `.php` but as simple text. If I rename the file into `Searchables` for example, it works fine.

Is `Searchable` restricted keyword or what?

[image]

[image]

It's not Laravel's problem, other projects do the same. So I guess it's in PhpStorm.

Comment: there is php tag in file, and I had created .php file using phpstorm gui

Comment: delete this file create again

Comment: I have done it, the same result.

Comment: Post your code as text....

Comment: if you have another editor with project and syntax highlighting features (like sublime, vim), once try with them. maybe you've also installed laravel-scout and it also has a searchable trait. and indexes might crash on that situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is Searchable restricted keyword or what?

Absolutely not.

> So I guess it's in PhpStorm

You are correct ... But it's user misconfiguration and not a bug.

Try to remember how you have created that file...

**In any case:**

- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
- Locate `Text` entry in top list, select it
- Now locate and remove unwanted pattern in bottom list -- will be something like `Searchable` or `Searchable.php`.

---

You can find more detailed explanation of how it possibly (most likely) has happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281563/783119